# Page filters not getting data from the database

Tags: php, mysqli, filter

This code is for some filters (dropdown menus) that I have on my page. I want these to work so when a user wants to filter some data, it will only show what they have selected. However, I have tried to implement that logic into my code and it doesn't work - just displays the error message that i have set even after I refresh the page a few times.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['search'])){

    $bedrooms= htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['bedrooms']));
    $radius= htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['radius']));
    $type_prop= htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['type_prop']));
    $prop_share= htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['prop_share']));


    $bed_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE prop_radius='$bedrooms'");
    $radius_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE prop_radius='$radius'");
    $type_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE prop_type='$type_prop'");
    $share_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE prop_share='$prop_share'");
    var_dump($bed_query);
    echo $radius_query;
    echo $type_query;
    echo $prop_share;
    }else {
    echo "This didnt work";     
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group" style="width: 400px; margin-left: 375px; margin-top: 20px; ">
      <label for="sel1">Radius (from Aston University):</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="radius">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="sel2">No of bedrooms:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel2" name="bedrooms">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="width: 400px; margin-left: 850px; margin-top: -152px; ">
      <label for="sel1">Type of Property:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel3" name="type_prop">
        <option>Halls</option>
        <option>Flat</option>
        <option>Terrace Home share</option>
        <option>Semi Detactched Home share</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="sel2">Property share:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel4" name="prop_share">
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="test">
  </form>
```

Comment: So, what's the scoop? I posted an answer for this over an hour ago, but no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form>` defaults to a GET method when a (post) method isn't implied and you're using POST arrays.

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

...is the same as doing:

```
<form method="get" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Add the (post) method to the form:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Sidenote: If you're not dealing with files, you can safely remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from the form but still add the post method.

However, if you later decide to process files, then use it. Processing files requires an explicit POST method.

If by chance no values are being passed, you may have to give them actual values.

For example:

```
<option>1</option>
```

to

```
<option value="1">1</option>
```

and follow the same procedure for the others.

`<option>Halls</option>` to `<option value="Halls">Halls</option>`

Note that `Halls` and `halls` isn't considered the same if `halls` is the value in your database.

Now, you're trying to echo your queries:

```
echo $radius_query;
echo $type_query;
echo $prop_share;
```

and that isn't how you pull information from your database to be displayed.

You need to loop over those results.

You want to use something like this for example:

```
while($row = $query->fetch_array())
  {
  echo $row['col1'] . " " . $row['col2'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

It's unsure if you've connected to your database using the same MySQL API `mysqli_`. If you haven't, then consult the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connect))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay... I have got it working now thanks to your response.

Comment: @JackDaniels No worries and you're welcome. Glad to see I was of help Jack, *cheers*.